# JavaFX 2.x : How to draw parallel line?

Tags: charts, line, javafx-2

This code below draw lines on an XY lineChart

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Lines extends Application {

Path path;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.5, 9.5, 0.1);
    yAxis.setTickUnit(1);
    //yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
    yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);
    yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            String label;
            label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
            return label;
        }
    });
    final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 4.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 2.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 6.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 4.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 8.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 6.5));

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setCenter(lineChart);
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 800, 600);
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);

    Lines.MouseHandler mh = new Lines.MouseHandler( bp );
    bp.setOnMouseClicked( mh );
    bp.setOnMouseMoved( mh );

    stage.setScene(scene);

    path = new Path();
    path.setStrokeWidth(1);
    path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    scene.setOnMouseDragged(mh);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(mh);
    bp.getChildren().add(path);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

class MouseHandler implements EventHandler< MouseEvent > {
private boolean gotFirst    = false;
private Line    line;
private Pane    pane;
private double  x1, y1, x2, y2;

public MouseHandler( Pane pane ) {
    this.pane = pane;
}    
@Override
public void handle( MouseEvent event ) {
    if( event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED ) {
        if( !gotFirst ) {
            x1 = x2 = event.getX();
            y1 = y2 = event.getY();
            line = new Line( x1, y1, x2, y2 );

            pane.getChildren().add( line );

            gotFirst = true;
        } 
        else {
            line = null;
            gotFirst = false;
        }
    } 
        else {
            if( line != null ) {
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();
                // update line
                line.setEndX( x2 );
                line.setEndY( y2 );
        }
     }
  }
  }
  }
```

I would like to copy (clone) a line once drawn, such as this picture

[image]

So, first left mouse click on point 1, then second mouse click on point 2: my goal is to have now a copy of this line (same lenght, same slope) that I can place anywhere on the chart, in this example by a third left mouse click on point 3.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you create another line with the same parameters as line 1-2?

Comment: Hi Bhupendra yes this is my target, but I do not know how to create another line that it should be the exact copy of what previously drawn

Comment: In the else clause where you do `line = null;`. Just before that create another line `Line l2 = new Line(line.getStartX() ... )`. And add it `pane.getChildren().add( line2 );`.

Comment: I have modified the code as
else {               
                Line l2 = new Line(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
                    pane.getChildren().add( l2 );                 
                line = null;
But it seems it doesn't work, third click draw another new line,not a copy of previous line.

Comment: This is what the logic should be ... 1) Determine the third click 2) Get difference between 3rd point and 1st point. 3) Your forth point will have the same diff. to point 2 as point 3 had to point 1. 4) Create and add the line.